Horrible eBPF performance of TC program on Rust + Aya when reading from HashMap
I'm currently mastering eBPF using Rust + Aya. The following problem has arisen. I'm making a port forwarding program using TC. I record incoming connections in a HashMap and indicate which port it was initially directed to. Accordingly, the outgoing connection from this map retrieves the source port. The problem is that productivity drops very quickly, by about 10 times. Moreover, if you redirect the port separately and read the card separately, then performance is maintained.
The problematic code with low productivity:
let key = RedirectLocalPortKey::new(packet.remote_ip(), packet.remote_port(), packet.local_ip());
if let Some(original_port) = unsafe { REDIRECT_EGRESS.get(&key) }.copied() {
    packet.set_local_port(original_port);
}

If use static data, the productivity is good:
let key = RedirectLocalPortKey::new(packet.remote_ip(), packet.remote_port(), packet.local_ip());
if packet.local_port() == 8081 {}
    packet.set_local_port(8080);
}

If read data from HashMap, then performance is maintained:
let key = RedirectLocalPortKey::new(packet.remote_ip(), packet.remote_port(), packet.local_ip());
if packet.local_port() == 8081 {}
    packet.set_local_port(8080);
}
if let Some(port) = unsafe { REDIRECT_EGRESS.get(&key) }.copied() {
    info!(ctx, "egress: {}", port);
}

Full code can see here.
Help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Please edit your title so that it's in English.

What does info!() do? Is it possible the compiler is optimizing out this statement and the preceding condition?

Yes, I think about that, but info! () shows the right port (8080).

Could be the branch prediction maybe (the first case is harder to predict than second and third), although that seems harsh as a performance reduction for that cause. I'd check branch predictions with perf. Other than that, the bytecodes for the first and third cases may help.
